# Does an SDN Controller need to be connected to every Openflow enabled Switch directly?

Tags: switch, sdn, openflow

Is it possible that the network would still function if the SDN Controller was only connected to one Openflow Switch and every other Openflow switch would be connected to that switch someway?

And if they need to be directly connected, since there would be lack of physical ports for that much connection, is it possible to use a regular switch in between the controller and other Openflow switches?

Comment: Unfortunately, the manufacturer of OpenFlow does not offer optional, paid support, and that is a requirement to be on-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: @RonMaupin manufacturer of a protocol or of an architecture ???? seriously ????? since when do protocols have manufacturers

Comment: @RonMaupin, alright.

Comment: @Effie if the question is regarding a protocol, then it would be practical to tie the question and answers to a specific implementation. Othewise it becomes too academic/educational. This site is focused on enterprise network design/support, not educational/theoretical protocol design. If the question was regarding a specific implementation in hardware/software that provides paid support then it would be on topic. There is no mention of specific hardware or software in use here so it is too vague to answer as it is.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer by this logic I can't ask question about how OSPF or STP or TCP works, and this is kinda bullshit. Where else are you supposed to ask these questions? Also, "design or theory of protocols used to operate a network (e.g. IP, TCP, routing protocols, STP, etc.);" are explicitly **on topic**, and SDN/OpenFlow is one of those.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer, would tagging HPE reopen the question, as I have HPE Aruba SDN switches where an SDN based network is expected to be implemented? But its not specific to HPE, its about the OpenFlow protocol and SDN architecture this question is about.

Comment: this is a moderation problem not a question problem (angryface emoji). And for the record, this site has very little traffic (compared to the rest of SE), it does not hurt to have a couple of extra questions, that are potentially sightly off topic, unless they do not clearly belong somewhere else. You know, it is kinda hard to gain rep if there are no questions to answer.

Comment: I think if the question is specific to certain equipment that does offer paid support then it might be ok to post a new question that covers the equipment and configuration questions. But if it is more about the protcol or configuration of systems/servers that are not part of a platform that offers paid support then it might still be off topic. I prefer things to be a bit more loose around here myself but the rules are the rules.

@Effie, I agree that those things should be ok, especially if related platforms that offer support or if they are the subject on their own.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer yes they should. A moderator should not close the question, because he does not know, or bother to understand, what it is about. This happens not for the first time.

Comment: The header shows 'needs clarification' so the original poster can edit the question to provide more information and have it opened again.

Comment: I researched the problem of how controllers connect to switches. This question is perfectly clear as it is, or at least not less clear than some questions which are not being closed. But at this point this discussion should be migrated to Meta. I am just too lazy to write a wall of text (for a very long time).